# Angular template ternary does not compile

Tags: angular

The following template expression gives me the following compilation error

```
{{
    antiAffineRules.length > 0
        ? 'vm.affinity.rules' | translate : antiAffineRules.length
        : ""
}}
```

> Parser Error: Conditional expression {...} requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

It is odd that I don't get this error when in development mode, so this must be different behavior between the jit and the aot compilers.

I'm on version 6.1.10

Answer (score 1):

That is because the parser got confused by the `:` that is used as the way to pass parameters to a pipe and also the ternary operator's second piece.

You can add `()` to help the parser

```
{{
    antiAffineRules.length > 0
        ? ('vm.affinity.rules' | translate : antiAffineRules.length)
        : ""
}}
```

Comment: So you answered your own question? :)

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis I did, I like to do that when I find something that could be useful to others that is not already on SO! See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ `it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.`